# Node.js + MongoDB global variable and scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, global, var

I'm trying to make a single connection to my MongoDB and store the response (database) I get back in a global variable, so I can re-use it in seperate JS file (like the separate files for my routes). I'm following this documentation as example: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connection-pooling.

First try:
    var mongodb = require('mongodb'),
        MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient,
        MongoURL = "my_mongodb_url:port/database_name",
        global.db;

```
MongoClient.connect(MongoURL, function(err, database) {
   db = databse;
   console.log(db); // shows stuff
}

console.log(global.db); // shows undefined
```

After some research I found a possible fix for the problem: create a global variable in Node with a global prefix. But it's still not working...

Second try:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb'),
    MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient,
    MongoURL = "my_mongodb_url:port/database_name",
    global.db;

MongoClient.connect(MongoURL, function(err, database) {
   global.db = databse;
   console.log(db); // shows stuff
}

console.log(global.db); // shows undefined
```

The code above is all put in the same file [app.js]. I think it has to do with the scope of MongoClient. But I'm not sure. Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's actually just an order-of-execution problem.  The `MongoClient.connect(...)` call is *asynchronous*.  The callback function you're passing is not invoked until the connection is established.  The `console.log(global.db)` that you have at the end, however, is invoked immediately, *before* the your callback is called.

You actually don't need to explicitly make `db` global here.  Variables defined in the outer scope of a module are in the global scope of the module.  Attaching a value to `global` makes it available across modules, but a better way to expose values between modules is to attach them to `exports`, so that they can be explicitly imported where needed.  If you're only using `db` within this module, then that's not necessary.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense! I'm indeed working with different modules, for example a routes module where I will use the db variable. I will read into ``export``. Thanks a lot. :-)